# Need to run jar file with `-Dos.name=windows` on a Mac, where can I put this in my Netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

When running my java program on a Mac, the Mac styling injects itself onto the elements, which messes up the GUI elements.

The solution I found to fix this is running the jar file from the terminal using this command:

`java -Dos.name=windows -jar myProgram.jar`

Is there a place I can put the `-Dos.name=windows` in Netbeans so the Mac user will not have to use the terminal to run the jar file properly?

Or is there any other solution like making a shortcut on the Mac which includes this command to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you running a jar file using Netbeans?

Comment: @BheshGurung The jar file is going to be used on its own on other employees computers without Netbeans, I'm kind of hoping that there is something I can change in the Netbeans compile so that it automatically applies the command

Comment: Might want to create batch/shell scripts to run this command. Or, you could use the [`System.setProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method in your code.

Comment: “Mac styling injects itself onto the elements, which messes up the GUI elements” —It shouldn’t.  You probably did something in your code you are not supposed to be doing, like forcing sizes or fonts or borders.

Comment: @VGR Interesting, so any place that I explicitly set size, fonts, or borders which wasn't set by using the Netbeans GUI maker might cause this problem?

Comment: Even the GUI builder doesn’t set those things (unless you specify a null layout, which is something you should never do).  Every component defines its own preferred size, which will take the Mac-specific look-and-feel into account.  Layout managers will respect those preferred sizes.